# Visual Studio, ASP.Net (.Net Framework) and including NuGet installed packages in a project

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio, nuget

I have an ASP.Net (.Net Framework) MVC web application in Visual Studio 2017 that is comprised mainly of JavaScript. I have used NuGet to install a package (specifically the [`marker-animate-unobtrusive`](https://github.com/terikon/marker-animate-unobtrusive) package.) The documentation goes on to say that i should include the JavaScript in my HTML pages but upon examining exactly what NuGet did I'm not sure how to proceed.

I have checked my `packages.config` file and have found a reference to the package, which I have also been able to find in the `packages` folder in the root of the solution. But these references indicate a TypeScript file - should I just be including that in my HTML?

And how would I do that, if that were the case? Should I route back to the packages folder? That seems like a bad idea, since that's not even included in my project. How can I dynamically link to what I've installed?

I am just getting to grips with Visual Studio and don't understand what it's doing some of the time, so any pointers would be helpful. In a broader sense, the two questions I'm mainly asking are:

- What is NuGet doing exactly when you install a package?
- How can these packages be accessed in the context of my web pages and JavaScript?

Comment: Is this a WebForms or MVC project? Do you want the js to be available for all pages within the site or just certain ones?

Comment: MVC - sorry, should have stated. I'll update the question. Just within certain pages, like you would include a JavaScript reference in an HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does NuGet do when you install a package? In this specific case it is extracting the js files to your Scripts folder and if any css is needed then it exacts the CSS files or in some cases folders to your Content folder of your solution.

If you want the js to be included on just certain pages and not all then at the bottom of the target pages (Views > Controller > Whatever.cshtml) you put the following lines:

```
    @section css {
        <link href="~/Content/Your installedCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" class="skins" type="text/css">
    }

    @section scripts{
        <script src="~/Scripts/YourInstalledScript.js"></script>
    }
```

What this is telling it to do is to find where you have the section "scripts" and "css" defined in your site layout page (Views > Shared > _Layout) and place the included files there.

Look for lines:

```
@RenderSection("css", required: false)

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: I see most of the packages I've installed in the Scripts folder, but not this particular one. Do you think that could be more of a problem with the library than what NuGet is doing?

Comment: Honestly, it really doesn't matter as long as you know where the files are located. Ideally they SHOULD be going in the scripts folder if the nuget package is targeting .NET MVC but this one may not be targetting this specific setup. You can still use it though as long as you know where the files are.

Comment: The one gotcha to this is that if you are working with other devs who go and grab your solution, it will try to resolve any nuget packages on initial build and if you decided to move them (and change ref to their location in your solution) then they will get a fat error when it tries to load the scripts. Just a catch to look out for.

Comment: So better to have everything I can in Scripts, right? Because that's conventional?

Comment: Personal Opinion: yeah, but I am a neat freak and most devs are anal about their structure as well.

Comment: Well, conventions matter when working with a team. Like I said, I'm new to Visual Studio and ASP.Net apps in general, and the structure is alien to me. But now I know - thanks